# Getting list of rows with id, grouped by other id

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using SQLite in Android (minSdkVersion: 15). I have table like this:
[image: Table]

I'm trying to get list of last inserted rows with `trainingId` as a parameter. For example, I'd like to get list of last inserted rows with `trainingId = 1` and the result should be:

`13---5---1
 14---5---1
 15---5---1`

or if `trainingId = 2`, then:

`10---4---2
 11---4---2
 12---4---2`

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name JOIN (SELECT MAX(trainingDoneId) AS trainingDoneId FROM table_name GROUP BY treningId) USING (trainingDoneId)
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE trainingDoneId IN (SELECT MAX(trainingDoneId) FROM table_name GROUP BY 1)
```

but in both cases I get this error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: aggregate functions are not allowed in the GROUP BY clause (code 1)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: hi @user3448282, did your issue resolved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please fire below query it will help you,

```
  SELECT * FROM table_name where trainingId = 1 AND trainingDoneId in (select max(trainingDoneId) from table_name where trainingId = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, MAX(trainingDoneId), trainingId FROM table_name WHERE trainingId = 1 ORDERBY id
```

Try with this solution

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I get error, that `ORDER BY` must be before `HAVING`, so I switched it and now I get this error: `near "HAVING": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM SeriesDone WHERE traning_id=1 ORDER BY id HAVING MAX(trainingDoneId)`

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE trainingId = 1 ORDERBY id HAVING trainingDoneId = (SELECT MAX(trainingDoneId) from table_name) try with this

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same: `near "HAVING": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM SeriesDone WHERE trainingId =1 ORDER BY id HAVING trainingDoneId = (SELECT MAX(trainingDoneId) FROM SeriesDone)`

Comment: try removing the HAVING statement and show me the result

Comment: `syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM SeriesDone WHERE trainingId=1 ORDER BY id trainingDoneId = (SELECT MAX(trainingDoneId) FROM SeriesDone)` I just read [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_having_clause.htm) that _The HAVING clause must follow the GROUP BY clause in a query and must also precede the ORDER BY clause if used._ In my first comment, I made mistake, I looked once again and there was mentioned that `GROUP BY` must be before `HAVING` statement.

Comment: omg, did you really only removed the HAVING word? Remove HAVING and everything after that. just leave " 
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE trainingId = 1 ORDERBY id "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116065/discussion-between-luca-nicoletti-and-user3448282).